# Javascript Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table

I'm having trouble the following table should read r1 c1, r1 c2, r2 c1, r2 c2 and so on in each box within the table and user should only be able to pick up to 12 rows and 12 columns anything over that should display an error message. Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

        <!-- written by Angela Bauer on 1/23/2013-->
        <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->


       <html>
         <head>
           <meta charset = "utf-8">
           <title> Dynamic Table </title>
             <script type = "text/javascript">


             var width = 500;
             var height = 500;

            function CreateTable(txtRows, txtCols, hold)
            {
            if(validNumber(txtRows) && validNumber(txtCols)
            && (hold != null) && (hold.canHaveChildren))
            {
            hold.innerHTML = "";
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.border = 3;
            table.borderColor = "Blue";
            table.height = height;
            table.width = width;
            var row = null;
            var cell = null;
            hold.appendChild(table);
            for(i=0; i<txtRows; i++)
            {
            row = appendR(table)
            for(j=0; j<txtCols; j++)
            {
            cell = appendC(row);
            cell.innerText = j;
            cell = null;
            }
            row = null;
            }
            }
            }

            function appendR(table)
            {
            if(table != null)
            {
            return table.insertRow();
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container Table is null!");
            }
            }

            function appendC(aRow)
            {
            if(aRow != null)
            {
            return aRow.insertCell();
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container row is null!");
            }
            }

            function validNumber(ipNum)
            {
            if(isNaN(ipNum))
            {
            alert("Invalid Number!");
            return false;
            }
            else if(ipNum <= 1)
            {
            alert("You can only enter a number from 1 - 12!");
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
            return true;
            }
            }
             </script>
        </head>
            <body>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td> How many Rows would you like: </td>
                <td><input type=text name=txtRows value=1 /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> How many Columns would you like: </td>
                <td><input type=text name=txtCols value=1 /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=10 align=right><input type=button name=cmdCreate value="Create Table" 
                onClick="CreateTable(txtRows.value, txtCols.value, divHolder)" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                <div id=divHolder></div>
            </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As gdoron put you need to ask a question but im taking a punt and guess you want you code fixed.

Below is a working copy of you code.  There was a ton of stuff wrong including

- No ID's on the input boxes
- No " used for the value of items within the HTML form
- .insertRow was missing a parameter
- .insertCell was missing a parameter
- The validNumber function was producing an error if you entered the
  number 1.
- canHaveChildren is only valid in IE i have removed it but if your
  script is going to be used in IE only then add it back

Things to be avoid for best practice:
using the words table, row etc as var names.

I guessing your new at this so my advice is to install Firefox and the firebug add on as it would have told you half the errors you were getting.
Also if its not doing what you want add alerts to sections of the code and work out where it is getting to or not getting to.

Hopefully this will get you on track.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> Dynamic Table </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        function createTable(txtRows, txtCols, hold) {
//                alert (txtRows+", "+txtCols+", "+hold);
//                alert (hold.canHaveChildren);
//                Removed as its an IE only javascript ----    && (hold.canHaveChildren)
            if(validNumber(txtRows) && validNumber(txtCols) && (hold != null) ) {
//                    alert ("is valid");
                hold.innerHTML = "";
                var table1 = document.createElement("table");
                table1.border = 3;
                table1.borderColor = "Blue";
                table1.height = height;
                table1.width = width;
                var row1 = null;
                var cell1 = null;
                hold.appendChild(table1);
                for(i=0; i<txtRows; i++) {
 //                        alert ("first for");
                    row1 = appendR(table1, i);
                    for(j=0; j<txtCols; j++) {
 //                            alert ("second for");
                        cell1 = appendC(row1, j);
                        cell1.innerText = j;
                        cell1 = null;
                    }
                    row1 = null;
                }
            }
        }

        function appendR(table1, i) {
            if(table1 != null) {
                return table1.insertRow(i);
            } else {
                alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container Table is null!");
            }
        }

        function appendC(aRow, j) {
            if(aRow != null) {
                return aRow.insertCell(j);
            } else {
                alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container row is null!");
            }
        }

        function validNumber(ipNum) {
            if(isNaN(ipNum)) {
                alert("Invalid Number!");
                return false;
            } else if(ipNum > 12) {
                alert("You can only enter a number from 1 - 12!");
                return false;
            } else if(ipNum < 1) {
                alert("You can only enter a number from 1 - 12!");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> How many Rows would you like: </td>
            <td><input id="txtRows" type="text" name="txtRows" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> How many Columns would you like: </td>
            <td><input id="txtCols" type="text" name="txtCols" value="1" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=10 align=right><input type=button name=cmdCreate value="Create Table" 
                                              onClick="createTable(txtRows.value, txtCols.value, divHolder)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="divHolder"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I caused, But yes I needed help and lots of it obviously! Thank You Very much!